# Should an application be using a single, or multiple Unit of Works?

Tags: model-view-controller, repository-pattern

I'm my implementation of the *Repository Pattern* with MVC I'm using EF as my DAL.  Each db table has an associated class in my EF context, and I'm implementing each table inside my **Unit of Work** (UoW) with their own repository.

Let's say my DB/EF has tables A,B,C,D,E, and I'm testing FooController which has requires A,B, C and BarController which requires C,D,E.

Should I create two UoW's (fooUoW, barUoW) or just one UoW?  I don't see any advantage of creating multiple UoW's, but the name "Unit of Work" implies I should be only including what is needed by the controller to do its job, no more and no less.

Answer (score 0):

One thing about unit of work is you need to ensure that for each request you only have one dbcontext for all queries that are related.  Therefore you either need to be very careful about how you manage your dbcontexts or you need to create a single unit of work that takes care of all of the work for a single web request.  It is definitely not advisable to create a UOW class for each entity in your model.